# Laravel Eloquent search JSON array for a specific column's value

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent `Book` model with a `readings (JSON)` field. It is an array of 12 positions, each corresponding to the number of readings of each book in each month of the current year, e.g.:

`[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2]`

In one of my controllers, I want to select all the books with *one or more readings*, by month. So I have a `for` loop which iterates over the months. The following is my best try, but the problem is that no books are selected with that query **in any iteration**, although the book from the example should be returned in all iterations except 2, 10 and 11:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $books = Book::whereJsonDoesntContain('readings->'. $i - 1, 0)->get();
    ...
};
```

I have also tried with `Book::whereRaw('not json_contains(readings->'.$i-1.', 0)');` inside the for loop, with the same luck.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses): "You may use `whereJsonContains` to query JSON arrays."
Since you are looping, you can/should use normal where query, `->where("readings->{$i}", '>', 0)`.

Comment: Thanks @zoispag, but your answer does not work, although it does not throw any errors. `$books` returns empty once more. Working with JSON is differently treated as I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `whereJsonDoesntContain` should work – it uses `JSON_CONTAINS` internally – but it converts this code:

```php
Book::whereJsonDoesntContain('readings->3', 0);
```

Into this query:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM books
  WHERE NOT JSON_CONTAINS(`readings`, '0', '$."3")
```

The problem with this is the invalid path; Laravel assumes an object key is being passed and not an array key, whose path should look like `$[3]`.

Similarly, a plain `where()` query like this:

```php
Book::where('readings->3', '!=', 0);
```

Is changed to use the same invalid path.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM books
  WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`readings`, '$."3"')) != '0'
```

So what we're left with is a raw query using `JSON_EXTRACT`:

```php
for ($i = 0, $i <= 11; $i++) {
    $books = Book::whereRaw("JSON_EXTRACT(`readings`, '\$[$i]') != 0");
}
```

This should return the records you need; a test fiddle of this query is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7466914080f01f9cd205066e57e88e90)

---

Note that this syntax:

```php
Book::whereJsonDoesntContain('readings->[3]', 0);
```

Should be working [in Laravel 9.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38391)

Comment: Thank you @miken32, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```php
$books = Book::whereJsonDoesntContain('readings', 0)->get();
```

Remove the `for` or any loop... `readings` is the field, in this case `1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2`...

Comment: I need the `for` loop because apart from the `$books` filtering, I do some other things inside the loop...

Comment: Question was looking for books read in each month, this only returns books that have been read in every month.

Comment: @miken32 that it is true, my bad

Comment: @andcl what column do you have to know when was it read? My query will work but for all books... And also, what do you need to do in the loop? You need to explain more...